# pandas.to_datetime: TypeError: invalid type promotion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I get

**TypeError: invalid type promotion**

at

```
df.iloc[1:,0] = pd.to_datetime(np.where(m, df.iloc[1:,0], np.NaN), errors='ignore')
```

in the below code.

It is because at df.iloc[1, 0], the empty value has m = True. How do I solve this issue?

```
m = df.iloc[1:,0].apply(lambda v: isinstance(v, datetime))
df1 ['Date'] = df.iloc[1:,0]
df1 ['m'] = m
print(df1)

df.iloc[1:,0] = pd.to_datetime(np.where(m, df.iloc[1:,0], np.NaN), errors='ignore')
```

**OUTPUT of df1 **

```
|Date            |  m   |
|                | TRUE |
|2000-01-31      | TRUE |
```

**Alternative**
I tested the below as well, but I still get same error at

```
df.iloc[1:,0] = pd.to_datetime(np.where(m, df.iloc[1:,0], np.NaN), errors='ignore')
```

Regardless if errors='ignore' or errors='coerce'

```
m = df.iloc[1:,0].apply(lambda v: isinstance(v, datetime) if pd.isnull(v)==False else False)

df1 ['Date'] = df.iloc[1:,0]
df1 ['m'] = m
print(df1)

df.iloc[1:,0] = pd.to_datetime(np.where(m, df.iloc[1:,0], np.NaN), errors='ignore')
```

**OUTPUT of df1 **

```
|Date            |  m   |
|                | FALSE |
|2000-01-31      | TRUE |
```

Comment: That is not an empty cell. I tried with an empty cell but the result is different.

Comment: Hi  keramat, I read in df from an Excel file and when I tested pd.isnull(df1 ['Date'].iloc[0]). I get TRUE

Comment: Check it before casting to datetime. It will helpful if you provide the first rows of df.

Comment: What are actually trying to achieve here? Convert only certain elements to datetime?

Answer (score 1):

The column was read in as datetime. Hence `np.NaN` led to the error in

```
np.where(m, df.iloc[1:,0], np.NaN)
```

Changing to `np.datetime64('NaT')`, solved the issue